# GitHub Pages not serving projects, renders the root user site instead

Tags: reactjs, github, url-routing, github-pages, static-site

I'm serving a React app out of the `bloom510.github.io` repository. There are 2 branches: `source` and `master`. As you might have guessed, source contains the entire non-compiled source code which is then built and deployed to the master branch. This works.

My problem is that other projects hosted on GitHub pages which GitHub says have been published successfully to `bloom510.github.io/my_project_name` simply load the root site containing the React app. In fact, any arbitrary route loads it without a 404 error. This is occurring on all my devices: Chromebook, MacBook, and Pixel 2 XL. What is going on here?

UPDATE: Currently hosting my main site in /card project and redirecting from main site. Would really like to get the main site working properly.

Links I have been working with:

user page: [bloom510.github.io](http://bloom510.github.io)

a project: [bloom510.github.io/hello-wasm](http://bloom510.github.io/hello-wasm)

an arbitrary route: [bloom510.github.io/i-do-not-exist](http://bloom510.github.io/i-do-not-exist)

repo:
[https://github.com/bloom510/bloom510.github.io](https://github.com/bloom510/bloom510.github.io/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Another peculiar observation is that loading project URLs in a private window actually works

I do see the "Hello World" using Rust and WebAssembly using http://bloom510.github.io/hello-wasm, in a non-private session.
Since the repo has a [`gh-pages` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/), its content is published.

[image: project repo]

So make sure you can reproduce the issue (in different browser or computer)

Comment: It's reassuring to hear that you see it. I've now tried it on three separate machines and continue to get the same results on my Chromebook and MacBook, and my phone, using Firefox or Chrome. Odd...

Comment: @bloom.510 I have added what I see, in my chrome 71 session on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried loading bloom510.art, and following that loading bloom510.art/hello-wasm? The project worked for me on the initial load, but after going to the user page and re-loading the project, it resulted in the described behavior ever since across all my devices and every browser.

Comment: Same. Maybe https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/547#issuecomment-348311408 (and answers below) can help?

Comment: Just changed the A records as advised and will report back once DNS propagation does its thing

Comment: The DNS records suggested in that thread use outdated IP addresses no longer in use. I don't think this is a domain name issue because it's happening on bloom510.github.io as well.

Comment: @bloom.510 And https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/547#issuecomment-354388495 or https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/547#issuecomment-398441313 in that same issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it look like it has something to do with react-router-dom v4. I got the fix by changing

```
<Router basename='/'>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

into

```
<Router basename='/yourCurrentRepository'>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

Seems like react-router-dom redirect your gh-pages into root directory wich is `bloom510.github.io` instead of `bloom510.github.io/my_project_name`. Hopefully can help everyone who is also experiencing the same problem.