# How can I host two Flutter web apps on GitHub pages?

Tags: flutter, github-pages

I created a Flutter web app and published it via my personal github.io repository site. This root site loads and works as expected.

I also created a simple HTML/CSS/JavaScript website and pushed it to a respository on my github. I published that site, as well, and it loads as expected. (From the repository home page I went to Settings, Pages, and enabled the respository as a GitHub Pages site by selecting its master branch for the Source setting.)

In other words, I can publish a flutter web app to GitHub Pages & I can publish more than one web site to GitHub Pages.

But when I try to publish a second Flutter web app, following the same procedures as for the simple HTML site, and even get the message from GitHub (with a green check mark) telling me my site's published, all that's displayed is my root github.io site. When I enter the URL I see the correct page title briefly flicker, but then root site immediately loads. (I have more or less the same issue as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085685/github-pages-not-serving-projects-renders-the-root-user-site-instead).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to host a Flutter web app at a non-root location, you need to follow the [instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies#hosting-a-flutter-app-at-a-non-root-location) for doing so:

> Update the <base href="/"> tag in web/index.html to the path where
> your app is hosted. For example, to host your Flutter app at
> myapp.dev/flutter_app, change this tag to <base href="/flutter_app/">.

You need to change your base to `<base href="/repo_name">`. If you did not already have a base tag, add it.

---

You might also be able to just remove the base tag if you had it set to the default of `<base href="/">`.

Comment: That did it. ... With a simple one-page/one-screen app I didn't even think about looking at documentation related to navigation or routing. Thank you!